# Why does Octave build not see Qscintilla or jni.h?

Tags: java, octave

I keep getting these errors upon setting up octave.

```
configure: WARNING: QScintilla library not found; disabling built-in Qt GUI editor
configure: WARNING: Include file <jni.h> not found.  Octave will not be able to call Java methods.
configure: 
configure: NOTE: Libraries or auxiliary programs may be skipped if they are
configure: NOTE: not found OR if they are missing required features on your
configure: NOTE: system.
```

I keep getting these errors when I try to run configure while installing octave. I don't know how to fix these and I've even ran

`CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include ./configure`

to no avail. How can I get octave to find QScintilla library and jni.h? I even installed libqscintilla2-dev. This is Ubuntu 16.04 btw.

Comment: [See here](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems) for dependencies, there is a Ubuntu 16.04 subchapter

Comment: The long story: the script "configure" creates a file "config.log", open it and have a look why it doesn't find QScintilla and jni.h

Answer (score 1):

This may be the case where octave is trying to use **Qt5** over Qt4.

If so, try running the command:

```
sudo apt install libqt5scintilla2-dev
```

This solved my problem with Qtscintilla.